# About re-use of a Private Key, after exporting it from an IIS server

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate, export

I have exported a Private Key from an IIS server using one of the many online instructions available. That particular IIS no longer is able to offer HTTPS anymore...

Has anybody been in the same situation before? Any solutions?

To be specific, what I am asking is that whether exporting a certificate means that it is detached from the IIS?

I am from Linux background, so be nice :)
Also it was a Wild-card cert, so I wanted to use it for another sub-domain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting a certificate and its private key does not stop that certificate and private key from being used on the server it was exported from - unless you explicit delete it after the export.

And having the PK still attached to that server does not stop the same PK being used on a totally different server.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! No I didn't delete it... But have you ever come across such a situation before, or heard of it? What could have gone wrong with my setup, what does your experience say?

Comment: Honestly; I can't actually tell from your question exactly what you did or what went wrong, I just took a stab in the dark about what you were actually asking about.